# Проблема с discord.py 1.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Решил поставить обновление библиотеки discord.py с версии 1.4.1 до 1.5

Выполняю код:

```
for i in _guild.members:
    yield i
output: (выводит только меня и бота)
```

Как быть?
p.s. в доках написано "members A list of members that belong to this guild."

Comment: Так в чем вопрос?

Comment: Как это исправить?

Comment: Что исправить? В доках написано выводит список членов принадлежащих этой гильдии. У вас выводит вас и бота. Есть ли там кто-то еще или нет вы не указали. Так в чем ошибка? Откатиться можно через `pip uninstall <имя_модуля>`, а затем установить нужную версию `pip install <имя_модуля>-<номер_версии>`

Comment: 255 человек на сервере

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Список он берет из инстанса гильдии, т.е. нужно использовать так:

```
@client.command()
async def hi(ctx):
    async for member in ctx.guild.members:
        yield member
```

Comment: А это есть в документации?

Comment: Конечно, там так и написано `class discord.Guild` Represents a Discord guild. This is referred to as a “server” in the official Discord UI.

Comment: Да просто уберите оба `async`

Comment: Мне нужно через цикл фор получить объекты всех пользователей на сервере.

Comment: Я заметил, что бот засчитывает всех, кто на воисе.

Comment: Нашёл ответ в документации:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#where-d-my-members-go